# Custom Query for wp_posts using wp_postmeta

Tags: query, sql

In postmeta lets say

1. meta_key = 'count' and meta_value = '5'
2. meta_key = 'count' and meta_value = '6'
3. meta_key = 'count' and meta_value = '7'

now i want to get all post

WHERE meta_key = 'count'

AND orderby = 'meta_value_num'

AND order by ASC

NOTE: I dont wanna use query_posts or wp_query. just custom sql query.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you wouldn't use WP_Query for that? There's the nice `meta_query` parameter that you can use. Otherwise It's not really a WordPress question because you basically need to inspect the WP database structure and construct a custom SQL query. You are getting downvoted because most users here advocate for doing everything according to standards and using WordPress' API where possible.

Answer (score 0):

While you might not want / be able to *use* native query, it is still the easiest and most reliable way to generate SQL like that.

`$wpdb->last_query` will remember last query performed and defining `SAVEQUERIES` constants will make `$wpdb->queries` contain all of the queries performed in current load (not advisable in production for performance).

So expressing desired query via API and looking at SQL that was generated for it is the best way to go about it.